# retrieve doc data, where condition value is a subcollection value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

my database on firestore looks like this:

```
Candidates
    |
    |______ID_1
    |        |_______likeDislikeSuper
    |        |              |___________ID_1
    |     ( data )                        |_______value: n
    |
    |______ID_2
    |        |_______likeDislikeSuper
    |        |              |___________ID_2
    |     ( data )                        |_______value: n
```

i want retrieve (data) from candidates where value == n

```js
firestore()
  .collection('candidates')
  .where('candidates/ID_1/likeDislikeSuper/ID_1', '==', 'n')
  .get();
```

**Candidates is a Collection, ID's are doc's, likeDislikeSuper is a subcollection of Candidates.

so... first params of `where` is a `camp value`, not support a `path`

does anyone know any way around this problem?

how could I return candidate documents using that value as a filter?

[image]

Comment: Your query is definitely not right. "/" is not a field separator, and you don't repeat the name of the collection in the field path.  But it's not clear to me what your structure is.  Are you showing nested maps in a single document, or do you have subcollections nested under documents in Candidates?  Please edit the question to be more clear abou the data you're working with.  A screenshot could be helpful.

Comment: hey Doug thanks, i edit with a screenshot and info about the struct. Yes the `where` it's incorrect, I did that to "symbolize" what I would like to return. Why don't I know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), as follows:

```
var likeDislikeSuperQuery = db.collectionGroup('likeDislikeSuper').where('value', '==', 'n');
likeDislikeSuperQuery.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});
```

The query will return all the documents under the `likeDislikeSuper` subcollections (**of all candidates**) with a `value` field equal to 'n'.

---

**Update following your comment:**

If you want to get all the `candidates` document that are parent of the `likeDislikeSuper` documents returned by this query you could do as follows:

```
var likeDislikeSuperQuery = db.collectionGroup('likeDislikeSuper').where('value', '==', 'n');
likeDislikeSuperQuery.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        const parentCandidateRef = doc.ref.parent.parent;
        console.log('parentCandidate path: ', doc.ref.parent.parent.path);
    });
});
```

However, this is not the most efficient approach, because several `likeDislikeSuper` documents may have the same parent `candidates` document.

You could duplicate your data and, for example, have a main collection of `likeDislike` documents for each liker/disliker ID which contain an array of `candidateId`s (or a sub collection of `candidates` document if you think the array could be so large that the document would reach the [1 MiB size limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields)).

Comment: would that return the "candidates" data collection? or would it return data from the "likeDislikeSuper" collection?
I was a little confused by the documentation

Comment: ok i try, but return the likeDislikeSuper documents, i want retrieve candidates documents :/

Comment: What do you mean by `camp` value in your question??

Comment: the first param of `where`, where(fieldPath, operation, value)

Comment: by the code I think that's right!

but I now have an error that I had before, and I don't know how to solve it

`
Error: [firestore/failed-precondition] operation was reject because the system is not a state required for the operation's execution. Ensure your query has been indexed via the firebase console.
`
thanks for your patience, i'm working with firebase for a little while

Comment: Yes, as explained in the reffered to in my answer [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query): "Before using a collection group query, you must create an index that supports your collection group query. You can create an index through an error message, the console, or the Firebase CLI... For the web and mobile SDKs, you must also create rules that allow your collection group queries".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query a user's likeDislikeSuper subcollection, you will have to build a CollectionReference to it:

```
firestore()
  .collection('candidates')
  .doc('ID_1')
  .collection('likeDislikeSuper')
  .where('ID_1', '==', 'n')
  .get();
```

Comment: I want to use a sub-collection value of "likeDislikeSuper" in where (), to retrieve candidate documents

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you're saying.  In your screenshot, likeDislikeSuper is a subcolleciton.  We can't see its document fields or values. Please edit the question to show an example of the documents you want your query to find.