# Accessing the collection inside a document of a parent collection in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to fetch the data of collection named **users** which has documents with an id of logged-in users' uid. Further, these documents contain some data and a subCollection called **posts**.
which looks like -

[image: database structure]

So now, I need to fetch all four(4) of these documents along with the **posts** collection data together so that I can display it.

My approach -
( here I fetched the document ids - middle section of image IDs)

```
// Fetching Firestore Users Document IDs

const [userDocs, setUserDocs] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = firestore.collection('users')
        .onSnapshot(snap => {
          let docIDs = [];
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            docIDs.push({id: doc.id});
          });
          setUserDocs(docIDs);
        })
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  }, [])
```

Now, I have tried to fetch the entire data using the following way (which isn't working)

```
// Fetching Firestore Posts Data

const [postData, setPostData] = useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
      try {
        userDocs.map(data => {
          const data = firestore.collection('users/'+currentUser.uid+'/posts')
          .onSnapshot(snap => {
            let documents = [];
            snap.forEach(doc => {
              documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
            });
            setPostData(documents);
          })
        })
      }  
      catch(err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
    }, [])
```

Finally, I should end up with postData array which I can map on my card component to render all posted images and captions to the UI.

I am not sure if this is the right way to achieve what I am doing here, please help me correct this error and if there's a more subtle and easy way to do it please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to set a listener (with `onSnapshot`) or you want to fetch all these documents only one time (e.g. with `get()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to fetch the entire data

Looking at the code you wrote for fetching "the entire data" (i.e. the second snippet) it seems that you don't need to link a `post` document to the parent `user` document when fetching the `post` documents. In other words, I understand that you want to fetch all the `posts` collection independently of the `user` documents.

Therefore you could use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

---

If you need, for each `post` document returned by the Collection Group query, to get the parent `user` doc (for example to display the author name) you can do as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239113/retrieve-doc-data-where-condition-value-is-a-subcollection-value/61239169#61239169), i.e. using the `parent` properties.

Comment: it worked using the Collection Group query. Thanks a lot.